# Need help with a an unfamiliar mathematical operation

Tags: probability, notation

What does (9 over 3) mean? I can't type the exact operation; please see attached. Or can you direct me to a site where this operation is explained?[image: 9choose3]

Comment: I think the answer is: [Binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: If the notation is $\binom93$ then it's certainly a binomial coefficient.

Comment: ... and does this book not explain this notation somewhere earlier?

Answer (score 0):

This is a notation that stands for "9 choose 3"

You probably know it as $${9 \choose 3 }= \ _9C_3$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dbinom 9 3$, pronounced "nine choose three", is the number of subsets of size $3$ of a set of size $9$.

This can be shown to be $\dfrac{9\cdot8\cdot7}{3\cdot2\cdot1} = 3\cdot4\cdot7=84$.